# OptimisticLockException using @Version vs ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, version

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Version
    private Integer version;

}
```

In concurent transaction I have an error OptimisticLockException because I used an @Version attribute. Without @Version I have an error:
ConcurrentModificationException.

What is the difrence between OptimisticLockException and ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: You're getting `ConcurrentModificationException` from `java.util` package?

Comment: @PiotrPodraza Yes it is from java.util package if I don't use Version annotation. On the other hand if I use Version annotation optimistic lock is enabled and I have an OptimisticLockException. So the same example when two transactions modify an entity throws diffrent error when I use Version and  when I don't use Version annotation.

Answer (score 0):

`OptimisticLockException` and `ConcurrentModificationException` (I assume it's from `java.util`) are two completely different exceptions and are not being thrown interchangeably.

First one, as its name suggest, are related to optimistic locking which basically means other transaction has committed changes to entities you were trying to update.

Second one is being thrown on concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible. For example when you try to remove an element from a collection you're iterating through. I cannot deduce from the snippet you provided what exactly triggers this exception in your case but it is not related to optimistic locking and JPA in general.